# RX 300 (2001) doors lock/unlock problem

Tags: locks, electronics, door, lexus, rx300

I have Lexus RX 300 (2001).

3 doors starts not responding to lock/unlock in most cases.

But sometimes works.

Only one rear and trunk doors works correctly.

Also works correctly  manually with keys.

Comment: You wrote **3 doors starts not responding to lock/unlock in most cases.**
  I assume you meant 3 door **LOCKS** ?

Comment: Yes, But after some period started working. 
Driver, Front passenger and left rear door locks were not working.
Tried lock from driver door panel and passenger door panel and not worked as well.
But front doors locks worked with keys from each door.

Comment: I read in forums that it can be actuator issue. But I don't think so, because   3 doors  started not lock together.